# How to remove all occurrences of a multiple occurring element in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

For example, removing the value 2 from the array

```
[1, 2, 3, 2, 4]
```

should produce the result

```
[1, 3, 4]
```

If I use filter it only removes the second and succeeding occurrences, which is not what I want.

All values that occur multiple times should be removed entirely.

Comment: You say you want to remove multiple occrrences, but then say that removing multiple occurrences is "not what I want"...?

Comment: i want all instances of a multiple occurring variable in an array to be deleted

Answer (score 4):

You can do this with `filter()` and return only elements that have same `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()`

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 1, 1];

var result = data.filter(function(e) {
  return data.indexOf(e) == data.lastIndexOf(e);
});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you previously sort your array you just then need to remove element which is the same as its neighbourg :

```
var input = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 6, 5 , 5, 1];
var result = input.sort().filter((x,i,arr) => x !== arr[i+1] && x !== arr[i-1]));
console.log(result); // [3, 4, 6 ]
```

Comment: But he wants to remove **all** the twos (and fives).

Comment: @torazaburo thank's for your hawkeyes. I've just edited to fix the bug

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is probably just to keep a map of any found items that occur multiple times, and always remove those in a filter

```js
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4];
var map = [];

var filtered = arr.filter(function(item, index) {
    if (arr.lastIndexOf(item) !== index) map.push(item);
    return  map.indexOf(item) === -1;
});

console.log(filtered)
```

Answer (score 0):

A proposal without sorting.

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 2, 4],
    filtered = data.filter(function (a) {
        return this[a] === 1;
    }, data.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a] = (r[a] || 0) + 1;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(filtered);
```